# vim+latex, can I compile using \ll without showing the Quicklist window and log file window?

Tags: vim, latex, latex-suite

I am new to vim+latex using latex-suite. So far it works well. I am enjoying vim. One thing I can't manage to get rid of is the two windows: Quicklist and log file, that appear automatically after calling `\ll`. I don't know how I can benefit from the Quicklist and log files. I just want to get rid of them. Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the compilation is succesful those two windows should disapear. You should look at the quickfix and try to modify your code to get rid of the errors/warnings there.

In general to close all other windows but the current one you just type `ctrl-w o` that is a `ctrl-w` followed by the letter `o`.

A bit of explanation required by @Anand:

There are several commands starting with `ctrl-w` followed by another key.
Some of the ones I use more often are:

```
ctrl-w + ctrl-w  -- change to previous window (same with ctrl-w+w)
ctrl-w + j       -- move to next window (down)
ctrl-w + k       -- move to previous window (up)
ctrl-w + t       -- move to top window
ctrl-w + b       -- move to bottom window
ctrl-w + c       -- close current window
ctrl-w + o       -- close all windows but this one (only window)
```

To get a more complete list and learn more about this from vim type `:he ctrl-w`

Comment: Dear skeept, thank you very much. Your command works well. I am content with this solution. I do have several warnings in compiling latex, which are not very serious. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Dear Skeept, can you explain a bit what `o` does here and in general? Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I just realized that instead of editing my answer, I edited your question... I will move the edits to my answer...